# Running two PHP versions on the same server using Apache

Tags: php, apache

I have two projects on the local server, one project is running PHP5.6 and the other one is running PHP7.0. Now would it be possible to enable these two versions based on the projects? I already tried adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .php` in one of the project htaccess but it's not working. Currently, PHP7.0 and PHP5.6-fpm have already installed on the server. Below is the screenshot of the `phpinfo()`.

[image]

Comment: what's the output of your `mod-enabled` in your apache directory ? are you sure that you have both of php5.x and php7.0x enabled there ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-version-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily this

Comment: Hi @HassanAhmed, only php7.0 and php5.6-fpm are enabled. When I enable php5.6 apache crashed. Maybe its confused what version to get.

Comment: Take a look at docker

Comment: have a look at this very well explained answer for debian / apache
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033511/how-to-select-php-version-5-and-7-per-virtualhost-in-apache-2-4-on-debian

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I finally managed to run my two projects in FastCGI on different PHP versions, thanks to the guys from the [PHP subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/42l8zl/how_to_run_multiple_php_versions_simultaneously/).

I uninstalled everything including Apache and started over again. Below are the steps I used to enable two versions of PHP on my local server. Btw, my computer is running on Linux Mint 18.

1. Assuming you already installed Apache, created virtual host for the two projects and added the necessary PHP PPAs. Let's call the projects `site56.local` for PHP 5.6 and `site70.local` for PHP 7.0. Install `php5.6-fpm` and `php7.0-fpm` by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm
   sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm
   ```
2. Create two files under `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` (honestly I don't know if this step is still necessary), and save:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi
   sudo nano /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi
   ```
3. Open the php56 conf file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php5.6-fpm.conf`, add this config and save:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
       AddHandler php56-fcgi .php
       Action php56-fcgi /php56-fcgi
       Alias /php56-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
       Action php70-fcgi /php70-fcgi
       Alias /php70-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
   </IfModule>
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
4. Now enable the new Apache config:

   ```
   sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm
   ```
5. If you installed php5.6 and php5.7, make sure you disable this two and restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo a2dismod php5.6 php7.0
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
6. Create a `.htaccess` file on the project that should run on php7.0 and add this handler:

   ```
   AddHandler php70-fcgi .php
   ```
7. Now create a phpinfo file on the two projects and if you see something like this, then congratulations!

PS: Make sure you enable `.htaccess` in your `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`

`site56.local/phpinfo.php`:
[image]

`site70.local/phpinfo.php`:
[image]

Comment: In case you want to have PHP 5.5.9 instead of PHP 5.6, then you need to install php5-fpm

Also, the contents of the php5-fpm.conf file should be as in this link: https://pastebin.com/3UgdxNV7

Comment: I also had to run `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml` as described in the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04)

Comment: I don't know if you even tried your solution properly step by step, because I'm getting this error when I restart Apache after enabling the php5.6-fpm conf
`Alias takes 1-2 arguments, a fakename and a realname, or a realname in a Location`

Comment: it's really great! but i need for centos

Comment: Does anybody know if I can use `mod_php` for all virtualhosts by default, and `php-fpm` (of a different version) for a specific `<Directory>`? `SetHandler` should have a priority, but unfortunately does not work for me (PHP module always takes over).

Answer (score 8):

**First of all, ensure all the PHP related configuration are disabled by running the following commands:**

# ls -la /etc/apache2/conf-enabled | grep php

# ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep php

**Set up a different version of PHP-FPM for a specific site:**

Add the following line to your existing VirtualHost file.

```
Include "conf-available/php7.2-fpm.conf"
```

For example,

# vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/symfony.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony.local

    Include "conf-available/php7.2-fpm.conf"

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony.local/curr/public

    <Directory /var/www/symfony.local/curr/web>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have both php7 and php5 installed on my local machine. but when I run "ls -la /etc/apache2/conf-enabled | grep php" as you suggested, I got empty output. Did I miss anything? thanks.

Comment: Empty output is the expected result. A list of available config and modules can be found here:

"ls -l /etc/apache2/conf-available/" and "ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-available/"

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work for debian 9 Stretch. It took me a while to firgure out what to do but at the end I found a solution which seems even easier :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm

sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm

sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm
```

If you installed php5.6 and php5.7, make sure you disable this two and restart apache.

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 php7.0

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

At this point all of your sites must work on php 5.6.

For the sites who need php 7, add this line in the vhost :

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/path/to/my/main/file"
```

It should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to implement Makubex's solution and it worked. There is just one problem I had with a newly installed LAMP and that was the fact that fastcgi was not enabled.
I just installed php again using the following script and enabled fastcgi afterwards.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php5.6-fpm php5.6 php5.6-dev php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mysql php5.6-zip php5.6-gd php5.6-xml php7.1-fpm libapache2-mod-fastcgi php7.1-fpm php7.1 php7.1-dev php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mysql php7.1-zip php7.1-gd php7.1-xml php7.1-curl php7.1-intl php7.1-json php7.1-mcrypt
```

And then:

```
a2enmod actions
a2enmod fastcgi
```

After this, the solution worked perfectly.
I got the two above from [Run multiple PHP version on the same server using php-fpm and xdebug on Ubuntu 16.04](https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/run-multiple-php-version-on-the-same-server-using-php-fpm-and-xdebug-on-ubuntu-16-04-6a84f5b7d7ce)

Answer (score 2):

We have got this covered in case of PHP on Ubuntu + Nginx:
https://blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-php-on-ubuntu/

**To change CLI PHP version**

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

**To change Web PHP version**

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

Where php7.2 can be replaced by the PHP version of your choice.

Comment: There is lot of answers like this one which are inaccurates for two version of php living **at the same time**: the question said "I have two projects on the local server, one project is **running** PHP5.6 and the other one is **running** PHP7.0". With `update-alternatives` there are everywhere symbolic links (`ln -fs`) like `/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock -> /run/php/php-fpm.sock` **or** `/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -> /run/php/php-fpm.sock`.

Comment: With `ExecStartPost=....install /run/php/php-fpm.sock` within `/lib/systemd/system/php5.6-fpm.service` **and** `/lib/systemd/system/php8.2-fpm.service`, ie pointing at the same path at the same time. Same for php binary of two versions.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this using `.htaccess` files**

First You need to install requred FPM using

```
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm
```

Then run below command

```
sudo a2enmod actions alias proxy_fcgi fcgid
```

Then Restart Your server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache
```

Then do below changes in `.htaccess` file

```
 <FilesMatch \.php$>
   # Apache 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
 </FilesMatch>
```

Here is example of running PHP 7.2 when PHP 5.6 is enabled

Comment: Thanks! I got an error from curl "[ErrorException]                                                                                    
  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_HTTPGET - assumed 'CURLOPT_HTTPGET' (this will throw an Error in  
   a future version of PHP) " 


So I ran 
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl 
to fix and it seamed to work

Answer (score 0):

After trying to follow your directions I found a possibly easier way for the same result.

By adding the following line

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/php70project/.*\.php(/.*)?$" "fcgi://localhost:9070/var/www/" enablereuse=on
```

in the apache vhost configuration, you could change the php version inside the directory php70project in your vhost root /var/www to version 7 running as fastcgi.

The following approach for use with unix socket

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/php70project/.*\.php(/.*)?$" "unix:/var/run/php70fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www"
```

is not working as intended.
Unfortunately i couldnt find the correct code to get this working but as there is no example for unix socket use with subfolder on that page https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html it might just not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is made a lot harder by all of the linux package stuff muddying the process. The easy manual, system independent way:

Build your 2 versions of PHP from source. You'll have say libphp7.so and libphp5.so in your modules directory. Just run a separate httpd.conf file for each. I ran 5 and 7 for years:

```
httpd-php7.conf
httpd-php5.conf
```

then. just put your virtual hosts that can't run 7 in the php5 config and either start them manually at boot or create the rc.d files or whatever your system uses for startup.