# How to select PHP version 5 and 7 per virtualhost in Apache 2.4 on Debian?

Tags: php, apache, debian, virtualhost, php-7

Would it be possible to run PHP 7 and PHP 5 simultaneously in Apache 2.4 on Debian 9? I would like to be able to select the PHP version I wish to use per virtualhost. I believe this would be useful considering that some of my websites still use deprecated PHP features. This allows me to perform upgrades per site. How do I achieve something like this?

**For example**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName mywebsite.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com

   # UsePHP 7
</virtualHost>
```

**And**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName mywebsite2.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite2.com

   # UsePHP 5
</virtualHost>
```

Comment: I think this is possible, but only if you are using FastCGI

Comment: http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/ This may help you.

Comment: @GeorgeJPadayatti: This is for a Windows environment

Comment: Hey the tutorial is explained in windows environment.

Comment: @GeorgeJPadayatti: I am not using Windows. I am using Debian

Comment: Does https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/42l8zl/how_to_run_multiple_php_versions_simultaneously/ help?

Comment: This question has already been answered : https://askubuntu.com/questions/749212/how-to-install-php-7-to-run-beside-php-5-on-ubuntu-with-nginx

Comment: @JayTeli This answer is for nginx, not for apache

Comment: this may help you... https://askubuntu.com/questions/50344/how-to-have-two-versions-of-php-installed-and-switch-easily-between-them

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Let's start from beginning. 
I assume that you would prefer to use php-fpm instead of Apache module.

First install apache:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Next install multiple PHP:

**Debian 9:**
Install PHP 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php-pear libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Configure repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add -
sudo echo 'deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb.sury.org.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Install PHP 5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-cli php5.6-fpm
```

**Debian 8:**
Install PHP 5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-fpm php-pear libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Configure repositories:
Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the following lines to the end of file:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

Install GPG key:

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-get update
```

Install PHP 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm
```

Next switch from prefork and enable necessary modules:
For Debian 8:

```
a2dismod php5 mpm_prefork
```

For Debian 9:

```
a2dismod php7 mpm_prefork
```

Next for both:

```
a2enmod actions fastcgi alias proxy_fcgi mpm_worker
systemctl restart apache2
```

Change content of `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf` to the following one:

```
<IfModule !mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Now create document root folders for websites:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/public_html
mkdir -p /var/www/test.com/public_html
```

Add sys users for these websites:

```
sudo useradd example --home-dir /var/www/example.com
sudo useradd test --home-dir /var/www/test.com
```

Configure ownership:

```
sudo chown -R example.example /var/www/example.com
sudo chown -R test.test /var/www/test.com
```

For example website `example.com` will use PHP 5 and website `test.com` will use PHP 7.

Create configuration files for websites:
Website on PHP 5:

```
touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
            Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
            Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-example.com
            FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-example.com -socket /var/run/php5-fpm-example.com.sock -pass-header Authorization
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Website on PHP 7:

```
touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.com.conf
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test.com.conf
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
                AddHandler php7-fcgi .php
                Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi virtual
                Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-test.com
                FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-test.com -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm-test.com.sock -pass-header Authorization
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Create pool configs (I used the following):
Website on PHP 5:

```
cat /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/example.com.conf
[example.com]
user = example
group = example
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-example.com.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
```

Website on PHP 7:

```
cat /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/test.com.conf
[test.com]
user = test
group = test
listen = /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm-test.com.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
chdir = /
```

Restart apache and php-fpm services:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2 php5-fpm php7.0-fpm
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I will try it out. I have one question. What is the difference between PHP-FPM and regular PHP?

Comment: Check the explanation at https://serverfault.com/questions/645755/differences-and-dis-advanages-between-fast-cgi-cgi-mod-php-suphp-php-fpm

Comment: By the way. You can achieve the same with the help of hosting control panel like Plesk. It will create all configuration for you =)

Comment: @Elvis Plesky, is it necessary to create users "example" and "test"? Can "www-data" be used for both?

Comment: Sure, but using separate users is more secure.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation I'm trying to use multiple php versions in debian stretch and apache. The problem is that I can't install libapache2-mod-fastcgi with my repos... Which one should I use?

Comment: @Rola, strange, it is available in Stretch main repository. https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libapache2-mod-fcgid

Comment: @ElvisPlesky the guide uses 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' and the link points to 'libapache2-mod-fcgid'... Are you telling me it is the same? If it is... After installing and enabling that module do I've to change some step more from this guide? Thank you

Comment: Somehow I can't get this to work, I had to edit all the php5 related strings for php5.6 and also my path for pool is a little bit different: /etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/ anyway I'm stuck with all the website running php7.3 probably because I can't manage to setup the repository correctly.

Comment: This fails to work (server returns a blank page, with no log information whatsoever). Doing everything, except Using a FilesMatch group with `SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm-sitename.com.sock|fcgi://localhost"`  instead of the `IfModule mod_fastcgi.c` section does work, but fails to handle index.php.

Answer (score 36):

The answer by **@elvis-plesky** is really detailled. But Apache [suggests](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP-FPM) the usage of `mod_proxy_fcgi`:

> With the release of apache httpd 2.4 upon an unsuspecting populace, we have gained some very neat functionality regarding apache and php: the ability to run PHP as a fastCGI process server, and address that fastCGI server directly from within apache, via a *dedicated proxy module (mod_proxy_fcgi.)*

Here are the steps to setup two vhosts with different PHP versions for **Debian 10** using Apache's mod_proxy_fcgi and php-fpm.

Configure repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add -
sudo echo 'deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb.sury.org.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Install needed PHP versions:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-cli php5.6-fpm php7.3-cli php7.3-fpm
```

Configure php5.6-fpm in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php5.6-fpm.conf`:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://php56.localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Configure php7.3-fpm in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.3-fpm.conf`:

```
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://php73.localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Now add a virtual host that uses PHP 5.6:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test-php56.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test-php56/"
    # use php 5.6
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://php56.localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

And a virtual host that uses PHP 7.3:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test-php73.localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test-php73/"
    # use php 7.3
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://php73.localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Activate the correct Apache module and the configs:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi
sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm
sudo a2enconf php7.3-fpm
sudo systemctl restart apache2 php5.6-fpm php7.3-fpm
```

The default configuration of the FPM pools should be correct already.

---

## Important:

This change will break old virtual hosts. You need to reconfigure all your virtual hosts and add the `FilesMatch` block which your project needs.
For example if your project needs php 7.4 then you first need to install the fpm package:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-fpm
sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
sudo systemctl restart apache2 php7.4-fpm
```

Then add this section to your vhost config:

```
...
# use php 7.4
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://php74.localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Then restart apache `service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best comment. This actually worked for me where I had a botched website which was not running with PHP 7.3. Worked flawlessly!

Comment: I find this one easier to follow

Comment: atm, I am trying to run a number of sites on PHP 7.2 (working) and one on PHP5.6. The 5.6 site's `info.php` is showing that it's using PHP7.2! Any hints for tracking down why?

Comment: @Auspex Sorry, but this is not enough context. You should provide all relevant configs, which is not possible in a comment ;-)

Comment: If it comes to that I'll need to post my own question, but I was just hoping for some debugging tips. I find it very difficult to determine what config any particular vhost is using. In any case, I think your solution is not complete. I'm finding that `a2enconf` for both PHP versions only enables ONE (the last one executed at apache startup, I think), and that I need to physically `Include "conf-available/php5.6-fpm.conf"` for the other site

Comment: This change destroyed other virtual hosts. I added a section to your answer .

Comment: This solution has 2 security problems. 

As-is it reveals the contents of any file named index.php, in contrast to using straightforward non-fpm apache. It also does not create separate users per site.

Comment: @aphid why does it reveal contents oft index.php files?  And of course this config is not meant as a complete config for a shared hosting environment. For those tasks you always need some extra config.

Comment: If the server is navigated to at "/" (so basically everyone just typing the name of the website), it will not forward to fpm (as FilesMatch won't apply, it won't see the extension). Adding `DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php` *before* the FilesMatch directive fixed it for me. This is part of the default config, it's just the default order that won't work properly.  
A .htaccess file redirecting everything will also work, though not be as pretty (clients don't want to see .php extensions in the address bar). The accepted solution does separate users, so combining the two worked for me.

Comment: @aphid even without the default `DirectoryIndex` config **no** contents of any PHP files are revealed. Only the directory content of the document root is shown. But this is a setting, which is out of scope of the topic, which is about "selecting the PHP version per VirtualHost"

Comment: This is all really great, I appreciate your post and the comments. After adding the handler section to each vhost config and restarting the services, I'm nevertheless having all sites, regardless of which php-fpm I've added in the FileMatch section, use php8.1. Does anyone know what part I could be missing, or how to track down the issue?