# How to use both PHP 5 and 7 per virtualhost in Apache 2.4 on Debian - with apache-mod?

Tags: php, apache, debian, apache-modules

Debian 9 *stretch* introduced a mechanism for two PHP versions to co-exist on one server. This makes sense when newer applications demand PHP 7.x (in my case Yii 2.0.12) while others (older) require 5.x.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033511/how-to-select-php-version-5-and-7-per-virtualhost-in-apache-2-4-on-debian), and answered "assuming ... to use php-fpm instead of Apache module". 
Now I want to continue using apache modules because of the experience with this setup, so other users and me don't want to switch to FPM.

Currently I have both php5-common and php7.1-common (plus related) packages installed. Apache serves PHP5, based on libapache2-mod-php5.

Now I installed:

> apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1

which ended sucessfully but with the hint:
"php5 module already enabled, **not** enabling PHP 7.1"

This sounds as if the two modules can only work exclusively.

I searched the debian docs but did not find hints on how to activate both and switch between them, per virtualhost. Same for the web, all howto's refer to FPM only.

Comment: use fpm with different ports

Comment: So it is not possible with apache-mod at all?

Comment: I have never run 2 differnt mod apaches at the same time. It could be possible but I dont know how

Comment: possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845963/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server-stretch
and / or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033511/how-to-select-php-version-5-and-7-per-virtualhost-in-apache-2-4-on-debian