# Running two PHP versions on the same server (STRETCH)

Tags: php, debian

I've followed this tutorial to have php 5.6 and php 7 on my server :
[Running two PHP versions on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696856/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server/46831696#46831696)

The thing is that I'm running on Debian 9 Stretch and the module fastcgi is not available anymore. There's proxy_fcgi but it doesn't include `FastCgiExternalServer`. I've read many things but I can't figure out how to replace it... Any idea ?

```
<ifModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
   AddHandler php56-fcgi .php
   Action php56-fcgi /php56-fcgi
   Alias /php56-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
   Action php70-fcgi /php70-fcgi
   Alias /php70-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
   Require all granted
</Directory>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what to do but at the end I found an easy solution :

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm

sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm

sudo a2enconf php5.6-fpm
```

If you installed php5.6 and php5.7, make sure you disable this two and restart apache.

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 php7.0

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

At this point all of your sites must work on php 5.6.

For the sites who need php 7, add this line in the vhost :

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/path/to/my/main/file"
```

It should do the trick :)