# Multiple php versions on centos 7. Php5.6 not loading mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, centos7

I have installed multiple php versions on my local centos 7 with apache. I followed this tutorial:
[Multiple PHP version with Apache on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004406/multiple-php-version-with-apache-on-centos-7)

PHP 7.2 is loading properly but I can't load mysqli on my 5.6 installation. 
phpinfo() does not show mysqli installed

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php56-php-mysqlnd
```