# CentOS 6 : php-fpm: unrecognized service

Tags: php, centos6

Please i'm using CentOS 6 and i've tried to install two PHP versions 5.6 and 7.2
first i remove existing php and all its packages and then i follow this link [Multiple PHP version with Apache on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004406/multiple-php-version-with-apache-on-centos-7)

but only php 5.6 is working and when i want to run php-fpm :

## service --status-all | grep php

=> 
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
WARNING: key file (/etc/rndc.key) exists, but using default configuration file (/etc/rndc.conf)
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
php-fpm (pid  17322) is running...
php-fpm (pid  17241) is running...

And when i type :

## service php-fpm

=> php-fpm: unrecognized service

the two versions of php are located respectively in : 
/etc/opt/remi/php56/
/etc/opt/remi/php72/

i think that system is not using this two new php

thank you and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Using Software Collections, designed for multi versions installation, each version have a different service name

- php56-php-fpm
- php72-php-fpm

Notice: To use recent PHP versions, I recommend you use a more recent version than CentOS 6 which is close to its end of live (later this year).

Also, multiple versions is far simple on CentOS 7 or 8 with apache 2.4 than on CentOS 6 with old apache 2.2 (which doesn't have the proxy to fastcgi feeature)

Comment: it's not so easy to upgrade centOS, i have multiple websites online and i'm afraid of not succeeding upgrade

Comment: In all case you will have to do it before Now 2020.