# antergos switch to php 7.0 from htaccess

Tags: php, antergos

On Antergos I have installed php7.0 from AUR and want to use this inspite of the default php7.3 on a project in my userdir.

I added `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php` to my local .htaccess file, but phpinfo still shows php7.3 is used.

I ave this in my httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp70.so
AddHandler php7-script php
Include conf/extra/php7_module.conf
```

I am pretty sure I was missing something simple but can not find out what.

Comment: NGINX or Apache? Web request or command line?

Comment: @JeremyHarris Apache and web request

Comment: Does your apache config have the module loaded?

Comment: @JeremyHarris the question is updated

Comment: Try commenting out the first one using `#` before it. Then reload apache.

Comment: Also, does your vhost config allow the htaccess overrides? If not, either enable it or move the handler config to the vhost.

Comment: Overrides are set all. If I comment out the above I get php 7.0 running for all sites. Anyway I am ok with that for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only load one module at a time. To fix current issue, add comment to the first `LoadModule` declaration.

```
#LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp70.so
AddHandler php7-script php
Include conf/extra/php7_module.conf
```

I think running multiple versions can be done with some setup. Maybe this will help: [Running two PHP versions on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696856/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server)