# Mcrypt PHP extension required on Mac OS X Mojave

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mcrypt, macos-mojave, php-ini

I just update my to Mac OS X Mojave. My local site now stop loading.

I kept getting

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

I tried

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php54-mcrypt
php --version // To Test your php
```

I got

> Error: php54-mcrypt: cannot load such file -- /usr/local/opt/php54-mcrypt/Abstract/abstract-php-extension

I tried reload my site

I still get this

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

---

My set up details

**php --version** , I got

```
PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: May  6 2017 10:02:00) ( NTS )                            
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group                                            
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies                    
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

**which php**, I got

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

**php -i | grep php.ini**, I got

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php5/lib                        
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

**printenv**, I got

```
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
CLICOLOR=1
TMPDIR=/var/folders/54/y_678c6n7q7_pgk1v5lkzwnr0000gp/T/
SSH_CLIENT=10.20.100.88 49732 22
OLDPWD=/Users/bheng
SSH_TTY=/dev/ttys016
USER=bheng
LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
MAIL=/var/mail/bheng
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/Users/bheng/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/local/mysql/bin
PWD=/Users/bheng/Desktop
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/bheng
GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always
LOGNAME=bheng
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

```
SSH_CONNECTION=10.20.100.88 49732 10.20.100.88 22
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

When I open up php.info I see this

[image]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with brew but php54-mcrypt seems to mean mcrypt for php 5.4 but you have php 7.1

Comment: Do you know how to install with the 7.1 ?

Comment: My guess would be `brew install php71-mcrypt`

Comment: I tried that I got this  https://i.imgur.com/VZMtQQP.png

Comment: What does `brew --version` returns?

Comment: @commonsense `Homebrew 1.8.6` https://i.imgur.com/8Y0KDGM.png

Answer (score 6):

Homebrew made some changes lately regarding PHP and its extensions. Before you had to tap `homebrew/php` and install a specific PHP version with `brew install php71` and a module with `brew install php71-mcrypt`. Now you have to use php@7.1 and build the extensions yourself using PECL.

Since you have so many different PHP version I suggest to get rid of them all. The following steps will remove all old PHP version from your system:

```
# Will show you any php packages you've got. make not of that!
brew list | grep php

# Will uninstall any php packages you may have
brew list | grep php | while read x; do brew uninstall --force $x; done

# You may need to run this too
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/php

# Clean up Launch Agents
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php*
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php*
brew untap homebrew/php
brew cleanup
brew update
brew doctor # just to make sure you're all clean
ps ax | grep php
# if some PHP daemons are still runing, reboot.
```

After the reboot you can install PHP the new way:

```
brew install php // This installs the latest version. If you need PHP7.1 use brew install php@7.1
```

Check if this worked:

```
php --version
```

The following important paths are:

- /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so — your apache module.
- /usr/local/bin/php — your command line PHP.
- /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm — your PHP-FPM binary.

To install extensions, you have to use pecl:

```
pecl install mcrypt // Install all other extensions this way
```

The extension will be installed to `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718/`.

If you use Apache you have to load the Apache module. Edit `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` and search for the section where all the modules are loaded. Add this line at the end of the section:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

Restart your Apache server and check if the correct PHP version is used.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue using laravel valet on macOS. I had to link PHP (brew) and it fixed the issue