# AWS host new version of web app on another port?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an new version of php web app listening to port 80.

I am wondering if it is possible to host the new version on another port, with no code modification, while keep the old version listening to port 80.

For example, if the user visits the page www.example.com, then it goes to the old version, and if the user visits the page www.example.com:8080 then it goes to the new version.

Maybe I can achieve this with route53? or maybe I have to alter the apache configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The way to achieve this is by tweaking the Apache configuration as you suggested, to force Apache to fetch your content from another DocumentRoot when the 8080 listener is triggered.

Route53 will not help here as a DNS system only resolves name to IP Address, and do not deal with multiple ports for the same IP address.

You can use Apache's [VirtualHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) to configure multiple listener.  You can even have different PHP versions per host ports, as per [Running two PHP versions on the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696856/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server)