# Downgrade PHP version Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is it possible to downgrade `Laravel 5.8` PHP version to PHP 5? Searched around for resources yet I can't find any.

I need to downgrade it so that I can upload it to our local `ubuntu` server.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8 "_Requirements: PHP >= 7.1.3_" Use a lower Laravel version then. Or upgrade to PHP7 on _your_ Ubuntu server

Comment: Downgraded it to `5.5` now. Is it possible to follow this tutorial?

https://medium.com/@abedxh/deploy-laravel-5-4-project-in-ubuntu-16-04-apache-based-server-538d4620bb97

the apache server required `PHP7`

Comment: 5.5 you say ... https://laravel.com/docs/5.5 "_PHP >= 7.0.0_" 5.4 is the last version to use PHP5.

Comment: Ohhh okay. Thank you. Is it possible to run Laravel 5.4 given the link that required PHP 7?

Comment: tbh I would do everything in your power to upgrade the server to php 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Laravel 5.8` requires `PHP` >= `7.1.3` because the code written in `Laravel Core` and in other `PHP Libraries` required by Laravel uses `features` and `functions` that are available only on `PHP` >= `7.1.3`.

An example is the usage of `??` (Null coalescing operator) which is supported only by PHP 7.1 and up.

In your case what you should do is utilize multiple PHP versions on your local server.

A guide on how to have multiple PHP versions using APACHE can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696856/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server) StackOverflow question.