# How to check if PHP CURL SSL works

Tags: php, ssl, curl, command-line-interface

I have two version PHP. PHP 5 and 7 (default version). In PHP 5 I must enable curl ssl. How do I check if CURL SSL works on PHP5?
Can I check it with a CLI command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, `php -i | grep openssl` will tell you if SSL is enabled. If you want to test the SSL protocol, just use `https://` in a curl request: `curl https://your_server_name`.

Comment: But curl request: `curl https://your_server_name` uses the default PHP, in this case 7?

Comment: I understand your point, you want to have two co-existent versions of PHP in your web server. Depending on your server config, you can achieve that with virtual hosts (apache) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696856/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server. Following the notation of the mentioned solution, you could SSL in PHP5 with `curl https://site56.local`.